# Clone OS to new micro SD for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, debian

If I clone the SD card on my original Pi to a micro SD on my Pi 2 will it run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; provided your OS is up  to date. If it is older to an `sudo apt-get update &&  apt-get upgrade` first to be sure.